# align="center" not working in Firefox and IE

Tags: css, html, firefox, internet-explorer-9

I have the following html page in which I have a menu at the top which is perfectly aligned. It is followed by an iframe which has some HTML5 animation and it is not aligning to the center in FF and IE, although it is working perfectly fine on Chrome and Safari. I have used the align="center" attribute everywhere required. How can I get the iframe to align itself to the center in FF and IE? Any help is appreciated.

The HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style_all.css" />
</head>
<body align="center">

        <table align="center" id="menu">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="index.html">  HOME  </a> </td>
            <td>&nbsp; | &nbsp;</td>
            <td><a href="HTML/about.html"> ABOUT US </a></td>
            <td>&nbsp; | &nbsp;</td>
            <td><a href="HTML/service.html"> HR SERVICES </a></td>
            <td>&nbsp; | &nbsp;</td>
            <td><a href="HTML/sport.html"> SPORTS &amp; ENTERTAINMENT </a></td>
            <td>&nbsp; | &nbsp;</td>
            <td><a href="HTML/contact.html"> CONTACT US </a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <center>

    <table width="100%" align="center"  style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: -moz-center;" align="-moz-center">
        <tr>
            <td height="100%">

                <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="HTML/homepage.html" width="100%" height="600px"> </iframe> 

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </center>

    <table width="100%" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td align="left">
            <p> Copyrights &copy; HUMAN CAPITAL RESOURCE </p>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
            <p>Created by <a href="http://www.pentafuse.com" target="_blank" id="penta"> PENTAFUSE INDIA PVT LTD </a> </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

The CSS file:

```
a
{
   text-align:center;
   font-size:16pt;
   color:white;
}
body
{
   background-image: url('../Media/bgimage.jpg') ;
}
a
{
   text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover
{
   color:#646464;
}
p
{
   color: white;
   font-size: 10pt;
}
html, body 
{
   margin: auto;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
}   
table 
{
   vertical-align:center;
   vertical-align:-moz-center;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: `align="center"` is deprecated, use `text-align:center` instead... just sayin' ;)

Comment: attribute `align` is no longer used , you have for this , `margin`, `float` and `text-align` , that should be used. html and body in absolute position is a nonsense too , vertical-align:center doesn't exist , is this question  a hoax ?

Comment: text-align doesn't really make sense because its an iframe, does it?

Comment: I want something that will work on all systems correctly irrespective of the screen size. So I can't really use margin and pixels anywhere! :(

Comment: is it the table with the iframe in it that you want to center horizontally or the contents of the iframe...?

Comment: @user3193036 you can believe that lots of ystem will understand basic CSS `margin:auto;` , `float` and `text-align` are part of CSS since ever :)

Comment: is there a specific reason why you'd use an iframe at all? I'd suggest you to try server side includes (SSI) instead if it's a page that you own, otherwise you may want to provide the full url of the external site as it's difficult to see what you see this way... I've started with a jsfiddle, [try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/7RUnB/) (I changed the body background to black as your background image obviously doesn't render)

Comment: @GCyrillus: I just made corrections as u mentioned. Nothing's changed!

Comment: @webeno: I want the table to be centered on the page and the iframe to be centered within the table!

Comment: @webeno: Yes its really neccessary for me to use the iframe. Its got HTML5 animation ( a couple of JS files). I can't do anything about that!

Comment: You should specify (in the question itself) *what* should be centered and describe what you mean by saying that it is not. What would centering mean to a 100% wide element? Moreover, you should try to reduce the problem to a simple, testable case using validated HTML and validated CSS.

Comment: @user3193036 yes it does : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/agjEq/ . width : 100% takes the whole width , nothing to center. do you have a sketch or screenshot of what you expect.

Comment: No you cant see the iframe at all. Its not gonna render on your system cause I haven't included those files. Check this out. The words flying around is the iframe. I want that centered in IE and FF - http://hcrconsulting.in/

Comment: it's centered for me in FireFox (Mac)...

Comment: Damn. The only option left is to use center tag in the iframe canvas. Which I did and it works. But it isn't supported on HTML5 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `margin: 0 auto`, but at first you have to use iframe (`iframe` is inline element by default) a block element.

```
iframe
{
   display: block;
   width: yourWidth; // place your width here
   height: yourHeight; // place your height here 
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

// Thanks for edit suggestion goes to @webeno (comments in css)

Comment: I find it interesting that you declined my edits, or do you know about CSS using variables, like you do with `yourWidth` / `yourHeight`? I think it might be misleading for some, so should probably be commented next to it at least...

Comment: @webeno I am terribly sorry, I am new here, I didn't know I am rejecting it. So... how do I undo it? Or how I edit it? Should I just edit it in my post, or there's a button for it?

Comment: think you just did it ;)